# Adding to a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I can't find an obvious answer this. I'm trying to add things to an array, so I assume I need to use an `NSMutableArray`

I have a ViewController (CVDownload) and and a TableViewController(CVTableViewController). The NSMutableArray is declared in CVTableViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cvFiles;
```

I then try to add a string to it in the CVDownload.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    CVTableViewController *controller = (CVTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [controller.cvFiles addObject:(@"sdsd")];
}
```

That doesn't work. I'm assuming because I haven't initialised the array. I've tried initialising the array in CVDownload.m

```
NSMutableArray *cvFiles = [NSMutableArray array];
```

but that doesn't work either. In debug, the array is still nil. I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Basically, my goal is to have an array in CVTableViewController that is used to populate a Table, and I want to be able to add to the array in CVDownload. Is there something I'm missing? Does NSArray have a similar method to NSString's stringByAppendingString?

Comment: Uh, you have to actually create the array before you can add anything to it.

Comment: (The first thing to do when you have something mysterious like this is to put a breakpoint in your code (eg, on the `addObject` statement) and do `po [controller cvFiles]` in the console window.  If it returns "<nil>" then that's your problem.)

Comment: you can generally init collection ivars in your init method... then you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `init` method of `CVTableViewController` write this:

```
self.cvFiles = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Just out of interest is there any major difference between putting that in the `init` of `CVTableViewController` or the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: viewDidLoad may be called more than once (it's pretty rare though) resulting in creating a new array and deleting all the previous elements. so you should stick to init methods

Answer (score 1):

```
CVTableViewController *controller = (CVTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

if(nil == controller.cvFiles)
{
   controller.cvFiles =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[controller.cvFiles addObject:(@"sdsd")];
```

Comment: Of course, that will create a new array every time that code sequence is executed, overwriting any pre-existing array.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing the array? Are you sure that it is created before prepareForSegue: is called?

// Edit: I ask because, [as confirmed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242935/adding-to-a-nsmutablearray/21242996?noredirect=1#comment32000610_21242996), the array is initialized after prepareForSegue: is called. The fix, as mentioned there, is to initialize the array in `-awakeFromNib` instead of `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm initialising it in the viewDidLoad of the CVDownload

Comment: viewDidLoad is called after prepareForSegue: is called on the view controller in question. And, viewDidLoad isn't called until the view is actually loaded (which happens after it is prepared). Try creating the array in awakeFromNib in CVTableViewController.

Comment: viewDidLoad is called after prepareForSegue? Really? Just to confirm that these are methods of the same class, CVDownload?

Comment: viewDidLoad of CVTableViewController is called after prepareForSegue: of CVDownload, yes.